# How to check if all employee in hashmap have name?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, logic

I have a HashMap of employees:

```
Employee{
  String name;
  String id;
  String Salary;
}

Map<String,Employee> emps = new HashMap<>();
emps.put("1",employee1);
emps.put("2",employee2);
emps.put("3",employee3);
```

I want have following scenarios:

1. All employees have name  ==>     Pass
2. All employess dont have name(name=null) ==>    Pass

**3. Other cases must throw an exception.
Example: employee2 does not have a name, but employee1 and employee3 do.**

How can I write such scenario?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: what's the key of your map? `emps.put(Employee)` will not compile

Comment: I answered you updated question with Exception is thrown if employees do not pass the requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Stream`s to filter employees that have or don't have a name, count them and compare the result to the size of the list.

```
long count = emps.values()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(employee -> employee.getName() != null)
                 .count();

/**
 * count == 0 => All employess dont have name
 * count == size => All employees have name
 */
return count == 0 || count == employees.size();
```

Comment: @TmP the same logic applies but you will need to manually iterate on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the values of the map by calling (map.values()) ,which give you Collection .Then apply your logic.

```
Collection<Employee> values = emps.values();
int count = 0;
for (Employee employee : values) {
  if(null != employee.name){
    count ++;
  }
}
return count == 0 || count == emps.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Get list of employees

```
     Collection<Employee> employees = employeesMap.values();
     testEmployees(employees);
```

The program will stop with an exception if employees do not pass the test. This is how to test them

```
     public void testEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        int nullNameEmployeeCount = 0;
        int size = employes.size();
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            if (employee.getName() == null) {
                nullNameEmployeeCount++;
            }
        }
        if (nullNameEmployeeCount == 0 || nullNameEmployeeCount == size) {
            System.out.println("All employees name are not nulls or nulls");
        } else {
            throw new EmployeesNotPassException();
        }
    }
```

And

```
public class EmployeesNotPassException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Pass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean res = true;
    for (Employee e : list) {
        res = res && isPass(e);
    }

    System.out.println(res);
}

public static boolean isPass(Employee employee) {
    if (employee == null)
        return false;
    if (employee.getName() == null)
        return true;
    if (employee.getName() != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(employee.getName())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: you cannot distinguish between 'all are null' or 'none is null'

Comment: @StefanWarminski &&ed

Comment: let's say the first employee's name is `null` -> `res = false`. Now the other emps will not given into `isPass` and `res` stay `false` even if a second emp has a name